# Fancybox navigation on Modx Evo doesn't work

Tags: jquery, fancybox, modx, modx-evolution

I have a problem with setting up a Simple Gallery and Fancybox on Modx Evo 1.4.0.
I installed both plugins. Here's the code that I use to call the gallery on pages:

```
[[sgLister? 
&thumbSnippet=`phpthumb`
&thumbOptions=`w=250&h=250&zc=1`
&tpl=`@CODE:
    <a href="[+sg_image+]" rel="group" class="fancybox">
        <img src="[+thumb.sg_image+]" class="img-thumbnail" alt="[+e.sg_title+]" title="[+e.sg_description+]">
    </a>`]]
```

The gallery appears on the page, but there are no navigation and close buttons.
I'm new to JS. Please, help me figure out where the problem is? 
Link to the page with the gallery:http://chreptowicz.tk/index/fotogalereya/usadba/oksana-pozdnyakova.html

Would be very grateful for any tips, thanx.

Comment: Open developer tools and check console. A message like "jQuery is not defined" should give a clue.

Comment: oh thanx, just changed the order of scripts and it worked!